# How to create N groups based on conditions in columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create groups using two columns. For example, I took `shop_id` and `week`. Here is the df:

```
   shop_id  week
0        1     1
1        1     2
2        1     3
3        2     1
4        2     2
5        3     2
6        1     5
```

Imagine that each group is some promo which took place in each shop consecutively (week by week). So, my attempt was to use sorting, shifting by 1 to get last_week, use booleans and then iterate over them, incrementing each time whereas condition not met:

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'shop_id':[1,1,1,2,2,3,1], 'week':[1,2,3,1,2,2,5]})

def createGroups(df, shop_id, week, group):
    '''Create groups where is the same shop_id and consecutive week
    '''
 
    periods = []
    period = 0
    
    # sorting to create chronological order
    df = df.sort_values(by = [shop_id,week],ignore_index = True)
    last_week = df[week].shift(+1)==df[week]-1
    last_shop = df[shop_id].shift(+1)==df[shop_id]
    
#     here i iterate over booleans and increment group by 1 
#     if shop is different or last period is more than 1 week ago
    for p,s in zip(last_week,last_shop):
        if (p == True) and (s == True):
            periods.append(period)
        else:
            period += 1 
            periods.append(period)
    
    df[group] = periods
    
    return df
createGroups(test_df, 'shop_id', 'week', 'promo')
```

And I get the grouping I need:

```
 shop_id  week  promo
0        1     1      1
1        1     2      1
2        1     3      1
3        1     5      2
4        2     1      3
5        2     2      3
6        3     2      4
```

However, function seems to be an overkill. Any ideas on how to get the same without a for-loop using native pandas function? I saw `.ngroups()` in docs but have no idea how to apply it to my case. Even better would be to vectorise it somehow, but I don't know how to achieve this:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we want to identify the promotions (continuously in weeks), then use `groupby().ngroup()` to enumerate the promotion:

```
df = df.sort_values('shop_id')

s = df['week'].diff().ne(1).groupby(df['shop_id']).cumsum()

df['promo'] = df.groupby(['shop_id',s]).ngroup() + 1
```

---

**Update**: This is based on your solution:

```
df = df.sort_values(['shop_id','week'])

s = df[['shop_id', 'week']]
df['promo'] = (s['shop_id'].ne(s['shop_id'].shift()) |
               s['week'].diff().ne(1) ).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   shop_id  week  promo
0        1     1      1
1        1     2      1
2        1     3      1
6        1     5      2
3        2     1      3
4        2     2      3
5        3     2      4
```

Comment: Very elegant pandas way! For non dummy data I had to also sort it by 'week' (since it's not in order, but it should be). However, it's 10x slower than mine

Comment: Yes, groupby is usually slower than sort and compare alone.

Comment: @simplymaxim see update for a vectorized version of your solution. Should see a bit of improvement in speed.

Comment: good solution. Now 2x faster, however, you can remove s and use df directly. Cannot edit now for some reason

Comment: @simplymaxim yes, you can use `df` directly. I thought I could use `diff()` on the whole thing. I was wrong :-).